# Jasper - Rasbery PI speech recognition free form dictation

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx

I am planning on using the Jasper API for creating a voice recognition program in Python for the raspberry pi. However I have been looking at the Jasper documentation and it all appears to work around keyword detection and searching predefined grammars.

This appears to have pretty good accuracy but won't be suitable for my project.

Is there a way to configure Jasper for free form dictation?
Are there any sources out there I have missed that can show me how to achieve this?

I have used the Google speech API previously with really good results in dictation, and I know Jasper can be configured to use this, but does it support dictation?

Thanks in advance for any information on this subject!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to configure Jasper for free form dictation? Are there
>   any sources out there I have missed that can show me how to achieve
>   this?

Jasper can be trained for free-form dictation. But as far as i understand, it is not meant for free-form dictation but for command-and-control hence it should not be used for dictation. Jasper is based on PocketSphinx. PocketSphinx is Speech Recognition engine implemented in C and maintaned by Carnegie Mellon University researchers. If you have not already you should read about PocketSphinx. Below are the links:-

[PocketSphinx: A Free Real-time Continuous Speech Recognition System](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~awb/papers/ICASSP2006/0100185.pdf)

[How to build and use PocketSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx)

> I have used the Google speech API previously with really good results
>   in dictation, and I know Jasper can be configured to use this, but
>   does it support dictation?

Theoretically it does support dictation because it depends on PocketSphinx but i don't think we should bend it to support dictation. Using PocketSphinx directly is a better alternative.

Comment: What I mean is Jasper doesn't necessarily depend on pocketsphinx as it can be configured to run google STT engine instead. However i'm unsure if this still depends on building your own grammars, or if you can just obtain the whole dictated sentence.

Thanks for the reply